# null portlet bag error while deploying the portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am facing this Error while deploying the portlet.

```
 Feb 24, 2016 10:19:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory E:\Temp_Vinita\runtime\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6\tomcat-7.0.62\webapps\Demo_RBMS-portlet has finished in 3,024 ms
    10:19:41,993 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-4][PortletContextFactory:77] Portlet demomoveinput_WAR_Demo_RBMSportlet has a null portlet bag
    10:19:41,993 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-2][PortletContextFactory:77] Portlet addfacilities_WAR_Demo_RBMSportlet has a null portlet bag
    10:19:41,996 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-9][PortletContextFactory:77] Portlet addroom_WAR_Demo_RBMSportlet has a null portlet bag
    10:19:41,997 ERROR [RuntimePageImpl-6][PortletContextFactory:77] Portlet Demo_RBMS_WAR_Demo_RBMSportlet has a null portlet bag
    Feb 24, 2016 10:19:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContextFactory._create(PortletContextFactory.java:84)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContextFactory.create(PortletContextFactory.java:40)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletConfigFactoryImpl.create(PortletConfigFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletConfigFactoryUtil.create(PortletConfigFactoryUtil.java:32)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:595)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:638)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:135)
        at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:141)
        at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:156)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:125)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.access$4(PortletRenderer.java:107)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:180)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:1)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.executor.CopyThreadLocalCallable.call(CopyThreadLocalCallable.java:69)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried to restart my Tomcat Server also try to run it on new Server but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

`Stop` tomcat. Delete your portlet inside `tomcat/webapps` folder. If necessary, also delete contents in `tomcat/temp` folder. Then `start` tomcat and `redeploy` your portlet again.